# Tag OBJECT html não carrega conteúdo PDF mobile

Tags: html5, objetos

Estou com um problema ao utilizar a tag object do html.

Na documentação diz que tem suporte, mas ao tentar carregar o pdf no mobile, não carrega, somente no desktop. Tentei com imagem para ver o resultado e com imagem carrega normal, tanto mobile como desktop.

Tentei como alternativa utilizar a tag embed, mas obtive o mesmo efeito. Também tentei usando url no lugar de base64, mesmo assim não funciona. No meu caso precisa ser base64.

```html
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64, xxx" type="application/pdf">
    <p>
        Arquivo não pode ser carregado. Faça o download 
        <a href="data:application/pdf;base64, xxx" download="Arquivo_TESTE">clicando aqui</a>
    </p>
</object>
```

Se alguém tiver uma solução alternativa para resolver, já encontrei bibliotecas JS que poderiam ajudar (mas não testei), mas eu queria manter o mais simples.

Obs: Se testar no desktop e depois com a ferramenta de desenvolvedor mudar para mobile ele permanece carregado com o conteúdo.

Comment: Cara esse seu data="" esta escrito bem estranho, pq está dessa forma?

Comment: é pq aonde fica o xxx depois coloco o base64, coloquei desta forma só para simplificar. <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,YOURBASE64DATA" type="application/pdf"></object> neste padrão

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Estou com mesmo problema

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui resolver, acabei mantendo assim devido a outras urgências, mas depois de muita busca e outros momentos que esbarrei nesse object me dando problemas novamente, acabei constatando que é problema com a engine de renderizar nos browsers e não foi resolvido ainda. É como muitos tem o Chrome como base, afeta em vários kkkk o melhor é o Mozilla firefox, mas acabei que não testei esse problema nele para ver.

Comment: Olá, já tentou adicionar um width e um height ao object? <object data="data:application/pdf;base64, xxx" type="application/pdf" width="100vw" height="860px"> por exemplo.